# Stop Background thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

This code successfully sends emails one at a time. 
My problem is stopping the emails when `Button2` is clicked. When `Button2` is clicked, the timer successfully shows the message confirming that `Session["stop"].Equals("true")`.
However, the emails are not stopping.. any help?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["stop"] = "true";
}

private void email()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++)
    {
        Thread email = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            SendMail(to, from, password, subject, body, amount);
        });
        email.IsBackground = true;
        email.Start();
        if (Session["stop"].Equals("true"))
        {
            email.Abort();
            return;
        }
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["stop"].Equals("true"))
    {
        Label1.Text = "Mail stopped. Sent: " + allMailSent;
        Session["stop"] = "false";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using a `Thread` instead of a `Task`?. As for cancelling, use a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: If `Session["stop"].Equals("true")` is `true`, then wouldn't better logic be to not start the thread in the first place. Here, you're starting it, then immediately checking to see if you really meant it, then attempting to kill it. Hmmm.

Comment: I'd also seriously recommend against keeping something that controls the state of threads in Session.

Comment: @ColinM I created a send mail button that isnt postback. This provides me with a live counter per email sent

Comment: @spender I feel sessions is the only way for a live counter per email sent

Comment: @chris - Calling `.Abort()` on a thread can cause the .NET run-time to enter an invalid state and corrupt the execution of all threads - for that reason the only time you should ever call it is when you are trying to forcibly shutdown an app. You should always construct your code so that threads end naturally.